# How can I round up numbers like 100.50 to 101?

Tags: php

Is there a way to round up in PHP numbers like 100.50 to 101

or 100.47 to 101 so that anything after the dot get rounded up to next positive number?

Thanks!

Comment: -1: A cursory scan through the mathematical functions aptly documented in the PHP Manual would have resolved this for you in mere moments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [ceil function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ceil.php)

```
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
?>
```

Comment: @Leigh No you can't. `round()` return the nearest integer and `ceil()` return the next positive number as asked in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

The ceil() function returns the value of a number rounded UPWARDS to the nearest integer.

**Syntax** ceil(x)

**Example**

```
<?php
echo(ceil(0.60) . "<br />");
echo(ceil(0.40) . "<br />");
echo(ceil(5) . "<br />");
echo(ceil(5.1) . "<br />");
echo(ceil(-5.1) . "<br />");
echo(ceil(-5.9))
?>
```

**Output**

```
1
1
5
6
-5
-5
```